# How to limit results with annotate and prefetch_related in django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-annotate

I'm have a django query with `annotate` and `prefetch_related`.

```
all_questions = Question.objects.all().annotate(is_complete=Case(
                When(
                    pk__in=completed_questions.values('pk'), 
                    then=Value(True)
                ),
                default=Value(False), 
                output_field=BooleanField()),
                votes_difference=Count('like')-Count('unlike'),
            ).order_by('votes_difference').prefetch_related('tags')
```

I want to limit the result to, let's say 100 objects.

I tried this query:

```
all_questions = Question.objects.all().annotate(is_complete=Case(
                When(
                    pk__in=completed_questions.values('pk'), 
                    then=Value(True)
                ),
                default=Value(False), 
                output_field=BooleanField()),
                votes_difference=Count('like')-Count('unlike'),
            ).order_by('votes_difference')[100].prefetch_related('tags')
```

I got this error message:

```
'Question' object has no attribute 'prefetch_related'
```

I checked the official documentation but can't seem to find any example related to it.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: just push [100] after the prefech_related

Comment: @WaldemarPodsiadło i already tried that, it gives `object of type 'Question' has no len()` error

Comment: It's strange error. I just try it on some of my classes and it works with annotate and order_by and prefetch_related. Limiting result should not interfere with queryset. oh by the way if you want only 100 results it should be [:100]. show your models